# белиберда вместо ошибок qt(c++)

Tags: c++, qt, кодировка, qtcreator

Что-то пошло не так,и в коде у меня появилась ошибка.Но вместо "Эй,где точка с запятой?" у меня выводится какая-то белиберда.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И вопрос,что делать???

Comment: *"- У меня что-то болит! - Выпейте какое-нибудь лекарство!"*

Comment: Что то точно у вас не так, раз написали такой вопрос...

Comment: логично,не правда ли?

Comment: Ща фото прикреплю...

Comment: Очевидно что надо погуглить как поправить кодировку на utf8, судя по фото - это именно оно. А компилятор выдает в кодировке консоли, это его вывод, он отличный от utf8